# How to proceed in this proof?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, pattern-recognition

Let 
\begin{eqnarray}
\eta(x) = \mathbf{P}(Y=1 \mid X= x)
\end{eqnarray}
and $Y\in \{0,1\}$. Assume $\tilde{\eta}_1(x)$ and $\tilde{\eta}_0(x)$ are some approximations of $\eta(x)$ and $1-\eta(x)$ respectively and sum of them is not one. Also, define 
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
0; & \text{if } \tilde{\eta}_1(x) \leq \tilde{\eta}_0(x)\\
1; & \text{otherewise}
\end{cases},
\quad g^*(x) = \begin{cases}
0; & \text{if } \eta(x) \leq 1-\eta(x)\\
1  & \text{otherewise}
\end{cases}.
$$
How to prove the following theorem: 
$$
\mathbf{P}(Y\ne g(x) )-\mathbf{P}(Y\ne g^*(x) ) \leq \int_{\mathbb R^d} \vert 1-\eta(x)-\tilde{\eta}_0(x)\vert \mu(dx) + \int_{\mathbb R^d} \vert \eta(x)-\tilde{\eta}_1(x)\vert \mu(dx).
$$
This is Theorem 2.3 from the book by [Devroye: A probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition](http://www.szit.bme.hu/~gyorfi/pbook.pdf).

Edit:

We know 
$$
\mathbf{P}(Y\ne g(x) )-\mathbf{P}(Y\ne g^*(x) )= \int_{\mathbb R^d} \Bigl\{\mathbf{P}(Y\ne g(X)\vert X= x )-\mathbf{P}(Y\ne g^*(X)\vert X= x )\Bigr\}\mu(dx),
$$
and
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}(Y\ne g(X) \mid X= x ) &= 1- \mathbf{P}(Y =  g(x) \mid X= x)\\
& = 1- (\mathbf{P}(Y = 0,\ g(x)=0 \mid X= x) + \mathbf{P}(Y = 1,\ g(x)=1 \mid X= x))\\
& = 1- (I_{[g(x)=0]}\mathbf{P}(Y = 0 \mid X= x) + I_{[g(x)=1]}\mathbf{P}(Y = 1\mid X= x)).
\end{align*}
Therefore, 
\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{} \mathbf{P}(Y\ne g(X) \mid X= x )-\mathbf{P}(Y\ne g^*(X) \mid X= x )\\
& = (I_{[g^*(x)=0]}\mathbf{P}(Y = 0 \mid X= x) + I_{[g^*(x)=1]}\mathbf{P}(Y = 1 \mid X= x))\\
&\quad - (I_{[g(x)=0]}\mathbf{P}(Y = 0 \mid X= x) + I_{[g(x)=1]}\mathbf{P}(Y = 1 \mid X= x))\\
& = (I_{[g^*(x)=0]}(1-\eta(x)) + I_{[g^*(x)=1]}\eta(x))\\
&\quad - (I_{[g(x)=0]}\mathbf{P}(Y = 0 \mid X= x) + I_{[g(x)=1]}\mathbf{P}(Y = 1 \mid X= x)).
\end{align*}
But how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\peq{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{}}\def\d{\mathrm{d}}\def\Ω{{\mit Ω}}$Define $η_1(x) = η(x)$, $η_0(x) = 1 - η(x)$. It is given that$$
η_1(X) = E(I_{\{Y = 1\}} \mid X),\ η_0(X) = E(I_{\{Y = 0\}} \mid X),\\
g(X) = I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) > \widetilde{η}_0(X)\}},\ g^*(X) = I_{\{η_1(X) > η_0(X)\}},
$$
thus$$
I_{\{g(X) = 1\}} = I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) > \widetilde{η}_0(X)\}},\ I_{\{g(X) = 0\}} = I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) \leqslant \widetilde{η}_0(X)\}},\\
I_{\{g^*(X) = 1\}} = I_{\{η_1(X) > η_0(X)\}},\ I_{\{g^*(X) = 0\}} = I_{\{η_1(X) \leqslant η_0(X)\}},
$$
and\begin{align*}
P(Y \neq g(X)) &= E(I_{\{Y = 1,\ g(X) = 0\}}) + E(I_{\{Y = 0,\ g(X) = 1\}})\\
&= E(I_{\{Y = 1\}} I_{\{g(X) = 0\}}) + E(I_{\{Y = 0\}} I_{\{g(X) = 1\}})\\
&= E(E(I_{\{Y = 1\}} I_{\{g(X) = 0\}} \mid X)) + E(E(I_{\{Y = 0\}} I_{\{g(X) = 1\}} \mid X))\\
&= E(I_{\{g(X) = 0\}} E(I_{\{Y = 1\}} \mid X)) + E(I_{\{g(X) = 1\}} E(I_{\{Y = 0\}} \mid X))\\
&= E(I_{\{g(X) = 0\}} E(I_{\{Y = 1\}} \mid X)) + E(I_{\{g(X) = 1\}} E(I_{\{Y = 0\}} \mid X))\\
&= E(I_{\{g(X) = 0\}} η_1(X)) + E(I_{\{g(X) = 1\}} η_0(X))\\
&= E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) \leqslant \widetilde{η}_0(X)\}} η_1(X)) + E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) > \widetilde{η}_0(X)\}} η_0(X)),
\end{align*}
analogously,$$
P(Y \neq g^*(X)) = E(I_{\{η_1(X) \leqslant η_0(X)\}} η_1(X)) + E(I_{\{η_1(X) > η_0(X)\}} η_0(X)),
$$
which implies\begin{align*}
&\peq P(Y \neq g(X)) - P(Y \neq g^*(X))\\
&= (E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) \leqslant \widetilde{η}_0(X)\}} η_1(X)) + E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) > \widetilde{η}_0(X)\}} η_0(X)))\\
&\peq - (E(I_{\{η_1(X) \leqslant η_0(X)\}} η_1(X)) + E(I_{\{η_1(X) > η_0(X)\}} η_0(X)))\\
&= \bigl(\color{red}{E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) \leqslant \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) \leqslant η_0(X)\}} η_1(X))} + E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) \leqslant \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) > η_0(X)\}} η_1(X))\\
&\peq + E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) > \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) \leqslant η_0(X)\}} η_0(X)) + \color{blue}{E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) > \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) > η_0(X)\}} η_0(X))}\bigr)\\
&\peq - \bigl(\color{red}{E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) \leqslant \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) \leqslant η_0(X)\}} η_1(X))} + E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) > \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) \leqslant η_0(X)\}} η_1(X))\\
&\peq + E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) \leqslant \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) > η_0(X)\}} η_0(X)) + \color{blue}{E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) > \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) > η_0(X)\}} η_0(X))}\bigr)\\
&= (E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) \leqslant \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) > η_0(X)\}} η_1(X)) + E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) > \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) \leqslant η_0(X)\}} η_0(X)))\\
&\peq - (E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) > \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) \leqslant η_0(X)\}} η_1(X)) + E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) \leqslant \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) > η_0(X)\}} η_0(X)))\\
&= E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) \leqslant \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) > η_0(X)\}} (η_1(X) - η_0(X)))\\
&\peq + E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) > \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) \leqslant η_0(X)\}} (η_0(X) - η_1(X))).
\end{align*}

Note that\begin{align*}
&\peq \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d} |η_0(x) - \widetilde{η}_0(x)| \,μ(\d x) + \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d} |η_1(x) - \widetilde{η}_1(x)| \,μ(\d x)\\
&= \int\limits_\Ω |η_0(X) - \widetilde{η}_0(X)| \,\d P + \int\limits_\Ω |η_1(X) - \widetilde{η}_1(X)| \,\d P\\
&= E(|η_0(X) - \widetilde{η}_0(X)| + |η_1(X) - \widetilde{η}_1(X)|)\\
&\geqslant E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) \leqslant \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) > η_0(X)\}} (|η_0(X) - \widetilde{η}_0(X)| + |η_1(X) - \widetilde{η}_1(X)|))\\
&\peq + E(I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) > \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) \leqslant η_0(X)\}} (|η_0(X) - \widetilde{η}_0(X)| + |η_1(X) - \widetilde{η}_1(X)|)).
\end{align*}
On $\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) \leqslant \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) > η_0(X)\}$ there is\begin{align*}
&\peq |η_0(X) - \widetilde{η}_0(X)| + |η_1(X) - \widetilde{η}_1(X)| \geqslant (\widetilde{η}_0(X) - η_0(X)) + (η_1(X) - \widetilde{η}_1(X))\\
&= (η_1(X) - η_0(X)) + (\widetilde{η}_0(X) - \widetilde{η}_1(X)) \geqslant η_1(X) - η_0(X),
\end{align*}
and on $\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) > \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) \leqslant η_0(X)\}$ there is\begin{align*}
&\peq |η_0(X) - \widetilde{η}_0(X)| + |η_1(X) - \widetilde{η}_1(X)| \geqslant (η_0(X) - \widetilde{η}_0(X)) + (\widetilde{η}_1(X) - η_1(X))\\
&= (η_0(X) - η_1(X)) + (\widetilde{η}_1(X) - \widetilde{η}_0(X)) \geqslant η_0(X) - η_1(X).
\end{align*}
Thus,\begin{align*}
&\peq I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) \leqslant \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) > η_0(X)\}} (|η_0(X) - \widetilde{η}_0(X)| + |η_1(X) - \widetilde{η}_1(X)|)\\
&\geqslant I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) \leqslant \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) > η_0(X)\}} (η_1(X) - η_0(X)),\\
&\peq I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) > \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) \leqslant η_0(X)\}} (|η_0(X) - \widetilde{η}_0(X)| + |η_1(X) - \widetilde{η}_1(X)|)\\
&\geqslant I_{\{\widetilde{η}_1(X) > \widetilde{η}_0(X),\ η_1(X) \leqslant η_0(X)\}} (η_0(X) - η_1(X)),
\end{align*}
and\begin{align*}
&\peq P(Y \neq g(X)) - P(Y \neq g^*(X))\\
&\leqslant \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d} |η_0(x) - \widetilde{η}_0(x)| \,μ(\d x) + \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d} |η_1(x) - \widetilde{η}_1(x)| \,μ(\d x).
\end{align*}

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much.